# I have a | separated file and want to replace columns 2, 4, 6, 7 dates from 20200929 to 20201007. excluding header/trailer

Tags: unix, awk

File e.lst:

```
H|data|ID|20200929|mni
1|20200929|mni|20200929|pqr|20200929|20200929
2|20200929|mni|20200929|abc|20200929|20200929
3|20200929|mni|20200929|lmn|20200929|20200929
4|20200929|mni|20200929|stu|20200929|20200929
T|count|123456
```

Command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} { $2=$4=$6=$7=20201007 } 1' e.lst > ne.lst
```

Above command adding extra fields in Header/Trailer records.

Comment: please add exact output required, should `20200929`  in first line be changed or not? if it should be changed, my suggestion in your previous question `sed 's/20200929/20201007/g'` is still the simplest solution, unless `20200929` can match in other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR>1 && FNR<lines{$2=$4=$6=$7="20201007"} 1' e.lst > ne.lst
```

OR

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < Input_file) '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
FNR>1 && FNR<lines{
  $2=$4=$6=$7="20201007"
}
1
' e.lst > ne.lst
```

***Explanation:*** Simply creating an `awk` variable `lines` which has total number of lines in it. Then in `BEGIN` block setting field separator and output field separator. In Main block checking condition if current line number is greater than `1` and lesser than `lines`(which has total number of lines value in it), then set fields to new value as per need. `1` is a way in `awk` to print current line.

---

---

***2nd solution(In single `awk` with reading Input_file 2 times):*** We could do this in a single `awk` by reading Input_file 2 times too, try like.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==NR{
  lines++
  next
}
FNR>1 && FNR<lines{
  $2=$4=$6=$7="20201007"
}
1
' e.lst e.lst > ne.lst
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** As per Sundeep sir's nice comment, in case your header and footer lines are lesser than 7 fields and rest of all lines of `7` fields then you can do this where we need not to count total number of lines in Input_file(but make sure about mentioned above conditions that your Input_file's all lines(apart from first and last) should be only `7` fields for this specific solution).

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
NF==7{
  $2=$4=$6=$7="20201007"
}
1
' e.lst > ne.lst
```

Comment: you could also use `NF==7` as an extra condition instead of counting number of lines in the input

Comment: @Sundeep, yeah sure thank you for suggestion. Let me add that now, since OP told to ignore only header and footer hence gone with this approach, let me add that one too now.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add a condition:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} $1!="H"&&$1!="T"{ $2=$4=$6=$7=20201007 } 1'
```

Alternatively, the same with a regular expression:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} $1!~/^[HT]$/ { $2=$4=$6=$7=20201007 } 1'
```